# i am new ruby on rails , i am trying to get the email_id of a facebook user but its giving me as "null". Here is my code :

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
client = FBGraph::Client.new(:client_id => Settings.fb_app_id,:secret_id => Settings.fb_app_secret,:token => params[:access_token])
         info = client.selection.me.info!
         status 200
        {
        :id => info.id,
        :profile_name => info.name,
        :first_name => info.first_name,
        :last_name => info.last_name,
        :authentication_token => client.access_token,
        :email => info.Email
        }
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough code to go on. How are you authenticating using the Javascript SDK or serverside?

Have you received the access token from facebook?

Are the other params from the user working, ie first_name?

Why is it info.Email I would have though it would be info.email but perhaps not?

Have you requested extended permissions? I don't think email is in the standard permissions scope

Some useful links

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas-games/authenticate/
https://github.com/nov/fb_graph
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Not really an answer but you haven't provided enough code or explanation to fully answer

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know if your other params are working as Jon Day said. If so, all you need to do is change info.Email to info.email.

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

The above omniauth-facebook readme provides examples of AuthHash you can call on. The :email attribute is nested under :info just like the :first_name, :name:, and :last_name params are. So if those are working for you, then info.email should work as well.

AuthHash from the link:

```
{
  :provider => 'facebook',
  :uid => '1234567',
  :info => {
    :nickname => 'jbloggs',
    :email => 'joe@bloggs.com',
    :name => 'Joe Bloggs',
    :first_name => 'Joe',
    :last_name => 'Bloggs',
    :image => 'http://graph.facebook.com/1234567/picture?type=square',
    :urls => { :Facebook => 'http://www.facebook.com/jbloggs' },
    :location => 'Palo Alto, California',
    :verified => true
  },
```